# Haskell "parse error on input `=>' "

Tags: haskell

```
first :: (a,b,c) -> a
first (x, _, _) = x

second :: (a,b,c) -> b
second (_,y,_) = y

third:: (a,b,c)-> c
third (_,_,z) => z
```

I got error message from this piece of code.

```
"parse error on input `=>'
"
```

I cannot see any reason. Could anyone help me to point out?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used bad lexeme: in first and second `=` and in third `=>`. Replace it with `=`.